# React via Webpack - Production flag increases file size

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build-tools

I'm pretty new to using React and Webpack so I'm likely doing something wrong, but when I build with the -p production flag my file size is considerably bigger (3.26MB vs 2.23MB) than when I build without.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-router": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "build": "webpack",
    "build-p": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": ""
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "app.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: When you open the bundle can you see that it's definitely been minified?

Comment: Also, separate to your issue, when using React you'll want to ensure the production version is bundled by setting `process.env.NODE_ENV` to production using the DefinePlugin otherwise the React runtime perf will be considerably slower. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#npm

Comment: Hi @riscarrott - Yes it is being minified. As for the production variable, I had come across that but I've been unable to figure out where I should set it.

Comment: http://dev.topheman.com/make-your-react-production-minified-version-with-webpack/ provides some info on compiling React in production mode. Re: the size difference it's hard to know why. Can you share your full code?

Comment: @riscarrott I'm afraid I can't share any of the code as it's for a project at work. Seems odd though, whatever my code consists of, that it comes out larger with the production flag =/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it got solved by removing the 'debug' property from webpack.conf.js. In stead I call webpack with the `-d` flag when I'm developing (and not when building the production bundle), as that adds the debug property automatically.

I see that debug is a conditional in your config, but at least it solved the problem for me.